# Perl CGI Form reusing previous data

Tags: perl, forms, cgi

I am building a signup form with Perl (using the [CGI](http://p3rl.org/CGI) module) and a recaptcha. The form works fine and submits the data to a SQL database. However, when I create another user with the form, the data entered into the database is the same as the first user. I am retrieving the form data in my verification page using `my $var = $cgi->param('param_name');` Do I need to clear the params, or is it something else. (I tried `$cgi->delete_all();` but that didn't seem to do anything)

Form Verification Code: (It is literally a prototype, so security has not been addressed yet)

```
my $challenge = $q->param('recaptcha_challenge_field');
my $response = $q->param('recaptcha_response_field');
my $username = $q->param('Username');
my $password = $q->param('Password');
my $name = $q->param('Name');
my $email = $q->param('Username');
my $security = $q->param('Security');
my $answer = $q->param('Answer');
my $permissions = 1;

# Verify submission
my $result = $c->check_answer(
    "my_private_key", $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'},
    $challenge, $response
);

if ( $result->{is_valid} ) {
    insert_new_user();
    print  $q->redirect('cgi-bin/admin/text_campaign.pl');
}
else {
    # Error
    print  $q->redirect('login.pl?crc=false');
}

###############################################################################
# Sub Routines                                                                #
###############################################################################
sub insert_new_user
{
    my $sql = "INSERT INTO users (u_username, u_password, u_realname, u_email, u_security_question, u_security_answer, PRIVILEGES_idPRIVILEGES)
               VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";
    my $sth=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($username, $password, $name, $email, $security, $answer, $permissions);
    $sth->finish();

    return;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it's the same? It's pre-populated when you load your form or you're saying that you get the same record after you insert? Are you using FastCGI or mod_perl or anything like that?

Comment: Hi, it's the same record. I fill out the form as 'new user 1' with some test info and submit it. This goes into the SQL database as expected, but if I go back to the form and fill it in as 'new user 2' with some different test info, it goes into the SQL database with the same info as 'new user 1'. It only enters different info if I modify the source file and the enter it again. I'm not using anything other than CGI and Captcha::reCAPTCHA modules.

Comment: Are you using GET instead of POST to submit the form? Maybe the values were in the URL already from the previous submission.

Comment: The documentation says to not use relative URLs in the redirect statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the way it normally works. Look into the -nosticky "pragma" in the documentation

http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#PRAGMAS

or the delete_all() function.

--- EDIT ---

I played a little with a modified form of the sample that is in CGI.pm's documentation. Including it here for ease of reference, and because i changed it a little.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw/-nosticky :standard/;

print header;
print start_html("Example CGI.pm Form");
print "<h1> Example CGI.pm Form</h1>\n";
do_work();
print_prompt();
print_tail();
print end_html;

sub print_prompt {
    print "<hr>\n";
    print start_form;
    print "<em>What's your name?</em><br>";
    print textfield('name');
    print checkbox('Not my real name');
    print "<p><em>Where can you find English Sparrows?</em><br>";
    print checkbox_group(
                            -name=>'Sparrow locations',
                            -values=>[England,France,Spain,Asia,Hoboken],
                            -linebreak=>'yes',
                            -defaults=>[England,Asia]);
    print "<p><em>How far can they fly?</em><br>",
        radio_group(
                -name=>'how far',
                -values=>['10 ft','1 mile','10 miles','real far'],
                -default=>'1 mile');
    print "<p><em>What's your favorite color?</em>  ";
    print popup_menu(-name=>'Color',
                            -values=>['black','brown','red','yellow'],
                            -default=>'red');
    print hidden('Reference','Monty Python and the Holy Grail');
    print "<p><em>What have you got there?</em><br>";
    print scrolling_list(
                    -name=>'possessions',
                    -values=>['A Coconut','A Grail','An Icon',
                            'A Sword','A Ticket'],
                    -size=>5,
                    -multiple=>'true');
    print "<p><em>Any parting comments?</em><br>";
    print textarea(-name=>'Comments',
                            -rows=>10,
                            -columns=>50);
    print "<p>",reset;
    print submit('Action','Shout');
    print submit('Action','Scream');
    print end_form;
    print "<hr>\n";
}

sub do_work {
    print "<h2>Here are the current settings in this form</h2>";
    for my $key (param) {
        print "<strong>$key</strong> -> ";
        my @values = param($key);
        print join(", ",@values),"<br>\n";
    }
}

sub print_tail {
    print <<END;
<hr>
<address>Lincoln D. Stein</address><br>
<a href="/">Home Page</a>
END
}
```

Left as is, this script exhibits the behavior we are discussing. The use of -nosticky doesn't seem to have helped.

However, if i add Delete_all after do_work and before print_prompt(), like so:

```
print header;
print start_html("Example CGI.pm Form");
print "<h1> Example CGI.pm Form</h1>\n";
do_work();
Delete_all();
print_prompt();
print_tail();
print end_html;
```

Then the defaults are not prepopulated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i'm not so sure about this. CGI should still be stateless. If it's a second request I see nothing in his code that would retrieve the previous values.  Nosticky just turns off the default values when the form is generated.

Comment: Well, we don't have the whole code and i'm going out on a limb, but the way cgi.pm is often used, is to have the same Perl script generate the form and process the POST request. When you POST to it, it processes the information, and then re-generates the form, reusing the posted values. Of course values are not preserved across different sessions, but you will see this behavior when the same user is making multiple posts to a cgi.pm script from his browser. I did a quick Google and also found out a few doubts and complaints about the -nosticky pragma, so more research may be needed.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've tried the nosticky pragma and using delete_all() but no luck so far, will keep trying as this makes sense that it would be the solution. I am beginning to think/already know that php would just be easier as the more I learn about Perl, the less I like it

Comment: If you post a sanitized version of your code, we may be able to figure it out. You no need no steenking php! :-)

Comment: I've had to change the front end development of the site to PHP anyway now, and the issue has now gone away. I have kept the code though and will try and figure this out when time permits :)